# Where do I find find web apps' .desktop files?

Tags: app-shortcuts, epiphany

I wanted to create an Inbox webapp. I tried epiphany and chromium but I wasnt satisfied with both.

Now I want to delete them but I dont know where to find the .desktop files?
Can anyone give the locations?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will find your `.desktop` files under `~/.local/share/applications/`

Answer (score 1):

You can delete Epiphany webapps completely from the browser, in the `about:applications` page. They also create a browser profile directory in `~/.config/epiphany` in addition to the .desktop file, if you have manually removed the .desktop files take also a second to remove the profile dir.

Answer (score 0):

You will also find them in /usr/share/applications

Comment: These are system-wide installed files, not user-made ones.

Comment: Good point lemonslice. I misread the initial post. Thanks!